# How do you assign commands to keys in Terminal?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there a solution to assign special key combinations to words in terminal use.
For example the less command is very usefull and i use i a lot to pipe the output of another process through it.

The idea would be to set up special key combinations that are only active in terminal use assigned to write different commands? So pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in terminal window could write

```
| less
```

or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> could stand for

`| grep`

Note: i just mean adding the letters to commandline not execute the finally. A similar way what's tabcompletion but more specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use the  bind command

```
bind '"\ey"':"\"less \C-m\""
```

That maps Alt-e to the less command and execute it (with the \C-m aka Ctrl-m )

Probably for the | you need to escape it.

```
bind '"\ey"':"\"\|less \C-m\""
```

If you want to just append it to the command line remove the *\C-m\""

Be careful as there are already some bindings defined:

```
Ctrl + A    Go to the beginning of the line you are currently typing on
Ctrl + E    Go to the end of the line you are currently typing on
Ctrl + L                Clears the Screen, similar to the clear command
Ctrl + U    Clears the line before the cursor position. If you are at the end of the line, clears the entire line.
Ctrl + H    Same as backspace
Ctrl + R    Let’s you search through previously used commands
Ctrl + C    Kill whatever you are running
Ctrl + D    Exit the current shell
Ctrl + Z    Puts whatever you are running into a suspended background process. fg restores it.
Ctrl + W    Delete the word before the cursor
Ctrl + K    Clear the line after the cursor
Ctrl + T    Swap the last two characters before the cursor
Esc + T     Swap the last two words before the cursor
Alt + F     Move cursor forward one word on the current line
Alt + B     Move cursor backward one word on the current line
Tab     Auto-complete files and folder names
```

The Control key, as you can see above, is made with C-m , so you can start the less command with Ctrl-g, as follow:

bind '"\C-g"':"\"\|less *\C-m\""

To get the key codes for the Alt (only for the ALT), you can use the read command from the shell:

```
@~$ read
^[y
```

^[y is equal to \ey

For more info, this question was answered also in stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119991/bash-call-script-with-customized-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: thanks, how can i delete a binding or show all bindings?

Comment: something is wrong with your first 2 examples. it always prints also the wildcard after less after i assigned with your binding syntax.

Comment: bind -p and bind -P will show you all the bindings.
I made a mistake with the star... I'm updating the answer

Comment: thanks a lot. perhaps do you have an idea how to reach the same goal in fish? i get it so far to work but the problem is that fish seems to automatically execute the command instead of just adding the string to commandline by default. here is the manpage http://linux.die.net/man/1/bind Unfortunately the example there is not very helpful for my case.

Comment: This is already a built-in function I think http://fishshell.com/user_doc/index.html#editor suing the Alt-p shortcut

Comment: thanks, great. also to see that the documentation page is up. some sites including google links to fishshell.org that is not available. however, i would still be interested how to teach fish to add a binding that it doesn't execute automatically. Perhaps you could have a look again at this question here?http://askubuntu.com/questions/20024/add-binding-to-fish-that-not-auto-executes-the-string

Comment: I've noticed that as well, I think they moved to http://fishshell.com/