# Add binding to fish that not auto executes the string?

Tags: command-line, fish, shortcut-keys

How do i set up a key binding in fish, so that fish understands not to execute the bindingstring after appending it to commandline but just appending it as string to commandline.

I want to set up a binding that appends `| less` by pressing i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.

It seems that by default fish understands the command to automatically execute.

I.e. When i type `ls` on commandline and then would press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> it only should complete the command to look like this `ls | less` but still not executing it.

i'm trying something like this

```
bind \ey " \| less"
```

But fish doesn't accept my [syntax](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append the |less at the end of the command line it's already a default function in fish, using the Alt-p

http://fishshell.com/user_doc/index.html#editor

You can create a function to do that if you prefer:

```
function __fish_less
       commandline -i -- "|less"
end

bind \ey __fish_less
```

I'm not sure if you need to escape the | make some tests...

**EDIT:**

Regarding append, the commandline help say:

```
* -a or --append do not remove the current commandline, append the specified string at the end of it
* -i or --insert do not remove the current commandline, insert the specified string at the current cursor position
* -r or --replace remove the current commandline and replace it with the specified string (default)
```

So to append instead of inserting a command, I guess you should use -a

Comment: tried that, good idea, but the problem is also with the function that it seems to "enter" execute at the end of the commandline and automatically executes it. perhaps when i want to make a binding for | grep this shouldn't be directly executed since i still have to add the search string in quotation to the end of the line?

Comment: updated with (I hope) the solution

Comment: thanks, tried it. but get the following error message: insertion mode switches can not be used when not in insertion mode. Also as far as i would understand it this could be a issue with using bind in fish with another option, since it always tries to execute it and not just adds strings to the line?

Comment: I think you are right. Let's see if anybody else as a solution, otherwise the best is to ask to the guy who developed fish (and then come back here with an answer).

Comment: ah, got it working. perhaps you can update your answer, so i will accept them. the problem in your example is the syntax. there are missing quotations, so the shell interprets the commandline in your function as a pipe of two different commands. It have to look like this commandline -a -- "| less"

Comment: Good! Congratulations. I'll update immediately.

Comment: yes, but now i have another question. do you know why bindings aren't saved persistently. I.e. i create a binding. it works. close terminal window. open a new one and then the binding isn't there any longer?

Comment: here's the link http://askubuntu.com/questions/20082/how-can-i-force-fish-to-save-new-key-bindings-persistently-after-closing-a-termin

Comment: You can add the bindings in the initialization files, like the ~/.config/fish/config.fish (maybe you don0t have one and you are using the default)

Comment: config.fish exist, but when i add the binding there, it doesn't work.