# How can I force fish to save new key bindings persistently after closing a terminal window?

Tags: command-line, fish

How can I force fish to save new key bindings persistently after closing a terminal window?

At the moment i have the problem:

- I open a terminal window, the default shell is fish.
- I add a key binding with: bind \eg functionname
- It works in the terminal window
- Now I close terminal window
- Open a new terminal window, again fish is default shell
- The binding doesn't work any longer and doesn't show up in output of `fish -a`

Answer (score 2):

You can add the bindings in the initialization files:

```
/usr/share/fish/config.fish
/etc/fish/config.fish
~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

For example you can add the following function:

```
function __fish_less
       commandline -i -- "|less"
end

bind \ey __fish_less
```

An example:

https://github.com/zmalltalker/fish-nuggets/blob/master/config.fish

**EDIT:**

From the fish shell [documentation](http://fishshell.com/user_doc/index.html#initialization):

> Initialization files On startup, fish
>   evaluates the files
>   /usr/share/fish/config.fish (Or
>   /usr/local/fish... if you installed
>   fish in /usr/local),
>   /etc/fish/config.fish (Or
>   ~/etc/fish/... if you installed fish
>   in your home directory) and
>   ~/.config/fish/config.fish (Or any
>   other directory specified by the
>   $XDG_CONFIG_HOME variable), in that
>   order. The first file should not be
>   directly edited, the second one is
>   meant for systemwide configuration and
>   the last one is meant for user
>   configuration. If you want to run a
>   command only on starting an
>   interactive shell, use the exit status
>   of the command 'status
>   --is-interactive' to determine if the shell is interactive. If you want to
>   run a command only when using a login
>   shell, use 'status --is-login'
>   instead.
>
> Examples:
>
> If you want to add the directory
>   ~/linux/bin to your PATH variable when
>   using a login shell, add the following
>   to your ~/.config/fish/config.fish
>   file:
>
> if status --is-login  set PATH $PATH
>   ~/linux/bin end
>
> If you want to run a set of commands
>   when fish exits, use an event handler
>   that is triggered by the exit of the
>   shell:
>
> function on_exit --on-process %self
>     echo fish is now exiting end
>
> Universal variables are stored in the
>   file .config/fish/fishd.HOSTNAME,
>   where HOSTNAME is the name of your
>   computer. Do not edit this file
>   directly, edit them through fish
>   scripts or by using fish interactively
>   instead.

So, you should edit the ~/.config/fish/config.fish, logout (or re-source the config.fish) and finally you should have your "custom bindings".

I kindly advice you to read the whole documentation and play a bit whit the shell, nothing that I wrote here doesn't come from the doc.

Then, if it doesn't work, come back here with logs (whenever available), config files, [debug](http://fishshell.com/user_doc/commands.html#breakpoint) output and so forth.

Comment: at first i put just bind \eg appendgrep to config.fish and it didn't work. second try was to put also the function in the config.fish file like this function appendgrep commandline -i -- "| grep \"" end but this also make no difference and doesn't work.

Comment: however, the defined functions via the functions directory seems to be persistent and are still available after closing terminal window and opening it. although they doesn't appear in the bind -f output. perhaps are there any differences that function need to be global or so?

Comment: Update: There shouldn't be no problem to use the bind commandline in the config.fish file as you also suggested, because it works in shell. However, will try to find the solution and put the answer in here, when i find out. i guess it can be also related to this question http://www.mail-archive.com/fish-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01956.html

Comment: I've a couple of doubts... 1. Use readline to be sure you are correctly mapping the Alt-keys combinations. 
2. Maybe fish is not reading the fish.config, so try to edit the system ones /etc/fish/config.fish and /usr/share/fish/config.fish . Look for strange conf parameters and add your function if needed.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660301) it seems you need to edit / create the file `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish` and e.g. for put there something like:

```
function my_func
  echo hello
end

function fish_user_key_bindings
  bind \eg my_func
end
```